# Google Login failed {error: 'popup_closed_by_user'} on Google login in Django

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, google-oauth

I am aware that this question has been asked multiple times. However, they were usually issues related to localhost.

I have a django site where I used react for the frontend.

Everything runs perfectly when I have my react at port 3000 and django at 8000. Even the google login

But when I run

```
npm run build
```

I pasted the build folder in the django root and make all the changes in settings.py

Now I directly went to localhost:8000
this error shows up on google login

```
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
Google Login failed {error: 'popup_closed_by_user'}
```

sometimes its even a 403 error.

I tried it on both localhost and heroku and it won't work.

[image]

I've been stuck on this for days. Would appreciate some help

Comment: it's saying Syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Your authorized javascript origin seems correct.

In the Authorized redirect URI you have also set the base url which is not correct. If you have used some package in django for google authentication; they have given you the endpoints. Like here is the example for the social-auth

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/
https://some-heroku-base-url/social-auth/complete/google-oauth2/
```